# python list of list comparing elements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to compare element of lists. I parsed data from a text file but I couldn't compare the lists.

These are the lists which I got after parsing a text file:

```
[['Detected', '1', '-9.5', 'S19960'],['Active', '3', '-14.3', 'S19966'],
['Detected', '10788', '-10.5', 'S19961']]

[['Active', '2', '-16.3', 'S15620'],['Monitored', '2', '-18.2', 'S15629'],
 ['Detected', '2', '-8.8', 'S1003H'], ['Detected', '2', '-10.3', 'S02965'],
 ['Detected', '2', '-6.3', 'S56615'], ['Detected', '2', '-20.8', 'S10105'],
 ['Active', '2', '-20.8', 'S06940'], ['Detected', '2', '-17.8', 'S52835'],
 ['Detected', '2', '-20.8', 'S5198E'], ['Detected', '2', '-21.2', 'S56749'],
 ['Serving', '2', '-12.2', 'S02035'], ['Monitored', '2', '-24.5', 'S04919']]
```

The code will find `Detected` elements and will check if -9.5 (the second elements of lists) is bigger than -12. If it's bigger it will check `Active` and `Servings` elements.

For example `-9.5 > -14.3`, if the difference is bigger than 3, the output will be for the first list:

```
S19960 > S19966 | S19961 > S19966
```

for the second list:

```
S1003H > S15620,S06940,S02035 | S56615 > S15620,S06940,S02035
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is a tad incoherent. Here's a link (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to improve your question. It has to provide us with enough information for us to diagnose the problem and propose a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working implementation, which first finds the indexes of the relevant `Detected` elements (with value bigger than -12) and of the elements to be compared (`Active` and `Serving` elements). It then uses those indexes to parse and compare values in the list and generate an output string:

```
def comparisonFromList(data):

    # find indexes of Detected elements with value > -12
    detected = [i for i in range(len(data)) if data[i][0] in ['Detected'] and float(data[i][2]) > -12]

    # find indexes of Active and Serving elements
    tocompare = [i for i in range(len(data)) if data[i][0] not in ['Detected','Monitored']]

    output = ""
    for i,detect in enumerate(detected):
        if i > 0:
            output += ' | '
        output += data[detect][3];
        output += ' > '
        for j,compare in enumerate(tocompare):
            if abs(float(data[detect][2]) - float(data[compare][2])) > 3:
                if 0 < j:
                    output += ','
                output += data[compare][3];

    return output
```

Output (based on the two input lists you provided):

```
> print(comparisonFromList(list1))
S19960 > S19966 | S19961 > S19966

> print(comparisonFromList(list2))
S1003H > S15620,S06940,S02035 | S02965 > S15620,S06940 | S56615 > S15620,S06940,S02035
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@glhr/55562796